# What does "outstanding" mean in specific economic term?

Tags: meaning

When I read a [webpage](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cashconversioncycle.asp), I saw the word "outstanding"

I am wondering what does "**Outstanding**" actually mean in these case on that webpage

Days of inventory **outstanding**

Days sales **outstanding**

Days payables **outstanding**

Comment: Yet to be resolved; not transferred from journals to ledgers, etc